# Prefix all JSON responses from ASP.NET Core to prevent XSSI attacks

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to prefix all JSON responses from ASP.NET Core with the well-known string `")]}',\n"`, to prevent XSSI attacks. (See https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/security.html#!#xss for more details.)

How could this be accomplished? I think I should use a filter or middleware, but can't quite work out the correct approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with a middleware or a filter like below:

```cs
public class EditResponseFilter : Attribute, IAsyncResourceFilter
{
    private const string _prefix = ")]}',\n";

    public async Task OnResourceExecutionAsync(ResourceExecutingContext context, ResourceExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var originBody = context.HttpContext.Response.Body;

        var newBody = new MemoryStream();

        //Body replacement is needed to make the response stream readable
        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = newBody;

        await next();

        newBody.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        string json = new StreamReader(newBody).ReadToEnd();

        context.HttpContext.Response.Body = originBody;

        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync(_prefix + json);
    }
}
```

Comment: I implemented this filter, but it had no effect on the JSON output. If I add a header to the response (`context.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("Test", "test");`), that does appear in the output, so I know the filter is getting executed.

Comment: @nw., I tested it in a typical MVC Core app. What is your environment?

Comment: I'm also using ASP.Net Core MVC, with VS 2017. I set a breakpoint in the filter and stepped through each line, and everything executes fine. Then in the response (I'm using Postman) I don't see the extra characters. Frankly I can't see why it wouldn't work, unless there is something else interfering with the response body.

Comment: LOL... as it turns out, it was working all along! Postman actually strips out those characters in the "Pretty" JSON view, probably because it's a common prefix.

Comment: I would like to have a similar thing without having to put an attribute on the api action methods returning Json. Is there a way to detect whether we are returning a json response and to put the prefix (or suffix)?

Comment: @stephan.peters you may register the filter globally to avoid attributes. Then check `Content-Type` of a request (or a response) inside the filter to determine should the prefix be added or not.

Comment: The problem is that  context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType and context.HttpContext.Request.ContentType are both null :(

Comment: After the await next(); the response type is defined. How can I execute this attribute optionally? Like what do I have to call to have the filter causing no impact?

Comment: @stephan.peters I guess you better to set up either a request or a server to have a `ContentType` explicitly set. It should be in response if you use `return Json(viewModel)` in your controller's actions

Comment: I have the contentType after the call to await next(). I'm trying to figure out what to do after the await next() in case I don't want to put the prefix (execute as if it would be original). What does the if(context.HttpContext.Response.ContentType != "application/json; charset=utf-8';") {   // WHAT THEN?? }

Comment: @stephan.peters just return the original body and write the response without prefix to it? `.WriteAsync(json);`

Answer (score 0):

I would like to have a similar thing without having to put an attribute on the api action methods returning Json. Is there a way to detect whether we are returning a json response and to put the prefix (or suffix)?

Comment: This post doesn't look like an attempt to answer this question. Every post here is expected to be an explicit attempt to *answer* this question; if you have a critique or need a clarification of the question or another answer, you can [post a comment](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) (like this one) directly below it. Please remove this answer and create either a comment or a new question. See: [Ask questions, get answers, no distractions](//stackoverflow.com/tour)