# .NET Core and Swagger UI preventing XSSI by prefixing JSON

Tags: json, angular, asp.net-core, swagger

I'm working with .NET Core API and Angular SPA APP. I prevented XSSI by prefixing JSON responses with ")]}',\n" string. Angular strips that prefix automatically. Solution is described here: [Prefix all JSON responses from ASP.NET Core to prevent XSSI attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44267012/prefix-all-json-responses-from-asp-net-core-to-prevent-xssi-attacks)

But I have a problem with Swagger UI. If I make a request using Swagger UI, I get response with status code 0 and empty body.

Does anyone know how to configure Swagger to strip that prefix?

Comment: Status code 0 sounds like a CORS issue. Are there any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @Helen There are no errors in browser console. It's not a CORS issue because if I remove JSON prefix, it's working fine.

Comment: @Algirdas Do you have a project showing your issue? Can you share a link?